# Why does the function getSafestCountriesNames() return promise{pending} when i call it and when i use async/await it returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

This is the function:

```
export const getSafestCountriesNames = async() => {
    try{
        const names = await getCountriesData();
        names.forEach((country) => {
            const {score} = country.advisory;
            if(score == 0){
                const liEl = createDOMElement('li', {className: 'name'});
                liEl.innerHTML = `${country.name}`;
                return liEl;
            }
        });
    }
    // …
}
```

When I am calling it in here I get `undefined`:

```
async function func(){
    const names = await getSafestCountriesNames();  
    console.log(names);
}
func();
```

Comment: The result of func should be undefined, it doesn't return anything. Do you mean that the console log inside func prints undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `Promise{pending}` because when a function has the `async` keyword, it has to return a Promise. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Nonetheless there's a deeper issue in your code. Your return statement is inside the  callback of the `forEach`. That's the return statement of the callback, not the one of `getSafestCountriesNames`.

Since you need to return a Promise (for you're using `await`), you can either wrap your logic inside something like:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // your logic here, resolving or rejecting instead of just returning
})
```

or keeping things simple: `return Promise.resolve("something")`

When you call the function with `await`, it resolves `undefined` because you're not resolving anything in your Promise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
do you mean that I should return a new promise where I used forEach, and then I can call the function without using async/await?

Comment: If you need to use forEach, use it, but your return statement should be out of it (unless you want to stop the callback in the forEach for some reason), and it should return a Promise. Then, you can call it anyway you want (async/await or `then`).